# Eclipse "Project does not have a recognized JPA platform: hiberate2_0"

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jpa

Move an EE project from Eclipse Indigo to Juno and get this error. Have anyone seen this? Where should I start looking?

If you need more info, just let me know.

**ANSWER:**  Just want to put in the exact solution based on the suggested by Brian Vosburgh.

The problem in my case is that the JPA facet does not have a JBoss runtime associated with it. So I go to the Project Facets setup and select JPA and select the desired Runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This likely because your Indigo workspace built a JPA project for the Hibernate platform using the JBoss Tools extension of Dali (which is the Eclipse plug-in that provides JPA mapping support). You need to use the Juno version of JBoss Tools.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not sharing or reusing the workspace (if that what you meant). I am re-import the project from the repository.

Comment: I am talking about the configuration of your project and your installed plug-ins. At some point, the JPA Facet was added to your project and it was configured with the Hibernate platform. (You should be able to see these settings in the Project Properties dialog Project Facets page.) This Hibernate JPA platform is supplied by the JBoss Tools plug-ins that extend Dali, which comes with the Eclipse JavaEE package. So, if you upgrade your executable to Juno, you will also need the JBoss Tools plug-ins for Juno.

Comment: I already have JBoss Tools plug-ins for Juno but I followed your instruction anyway and found that the problem is my JBoss server runtime is not checked to be used for the JPA facets (Server upgrade was the reason why I change to Juno). Thanks a lot for your help.